# Animating children element in Polymer

Tags: animation, polymer, css-animations, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to animate children elements without wrapping them in a custom-element that has `Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior`? It seems to be overkill to have to wrap each animatable element as a custom element.

Comment: using `node` property of `animationConfig` you should be able to give animations to child elements. Something like `node: this.$.placeholder`

Comment: I think I'm getting what you're saying. Do you have an example of this solution?

Comment: You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/demo/card/x-card.html#L55-L59) code for example.

Comment: Thanks. If you'd write an official answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use[`neon-animatable`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation?active=neon-animatable)

> is a simple container element implementing Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior. This is a convenience element for use with `<neon-animated-pages>`.

```
 <neon-animated-pages selected="0"
                 entry-animation="slide-from-right-animation"
                 exit-animation="slide-left-animation">
  <neon-animatable>1</neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable>2</neon-animatable>
 </neon-animated-pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate an element inside a custom element by using the `node` property of
`animationConfig` Object. It'll be something like

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
<script>
 //rest of the code
 properties:{
  animationConfig:{
   value:function(){
    return {'entry':[{
     name: '<name of the animation>',
     node: this.$.placeholder
    }]}
```

Where `placeholder` is the element to animate. You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/blob/master/demo/card/x-card.html#L55-L59) `neon-animation` example for complete code.